# How to make tkinter text bob up and down slowly

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

I am making a game, and I am trying to make the title bob up and down like it's in water. How do I do this?

I have tried using `intro.move()`, but I realized that this is a non-existent function.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

root = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500, bg='limegreen')

intro = root.create_text(250, 250, anchor=CENTER, text='foo', fill='black')
# intro.move() This is non-existent.

root.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I know that `intro.move()` won't work, but I can't find any other way. How do I make the text move up and down?

Comment: `intro` is ID of created text and you can use this ID to move object with `canvas.move(ID, ...)`

Comment: Hi @furas! So how do I move the text with `canvas.move(ID, ...`?

Comment: you will need `window.after(time_in_ms, function_name)` to run function after `time_in_ms` which will move object and run `after(...)` again.

Comment: I have example [how to use after() to display current time](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/timer-using-after/clock-function.py)

Comment: Could you explain further? I don't get what you mean by `function_name`. Is that the function that moves the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very basic example that moves it up and down:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

root = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500, bg='limegreen')

intro = root.create_text(250, 250, anchor=CENTER, font=('Calibri', 48), text=' Welcome to the \n     Putt Tracker', fill='black')
# intro.move() This is non-existent.

max_mov, min_mov = 5, -5
mov = max_mov
speed = 0.5
def bob():
    global mov, speed
    root.move(intro, 0, mov)
    if mov == max_mov:
        speed = -abs(speed)
    elif mov == -min_mov:
        speed = abs(speed)
    mov += speed
    mov = round(mov, 2)
    window.after(10, bob)

window.after(10, bob)

root.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Try tinkering with the `speed` and `mov` variables to produce the effect you want.

Comment: Do I need any other modules for this?

Comment: Also, when I try this, the intro text flies off the screen :( How do I fix this?

Comment: This almost definitely due to floating-point errors. Maybe try `if round(mov) == max_mov)`? Or try `if mov > max_mov` and `if mov < min_mov`

Comment: I just changed it so the min and max mov is 0.5, and the speed is 0.01 so it moves slowly. Thanks though!